# Order of columns in compound indexes

Tags: postgresql, query-performance

I am using a compound index on a table with more than 13 million records.
The `index order is (center_code, created_on, status)`. The center_code and status both are varchar(100) not NULL and created_on is timestamp without time zone.

I read somewhere that order of indexes matter in a compound index. We have to check for number of unique values and put the one with the highest number of unique values at the first place in compound index.

- The center_code can have 4000 distinct values.
- The status can have 5 distinct values.
- The min value of created_on is `2017-12-12 02:00:49.465317+00`.

The question is what can be the number of unique values for created_on?
Should I put it first in the compound index?

Indexing on date column works on date basis, hour basis or second basis.

The problem is:

A simple SELECT query is taking more than 500 ms which is using just this compound index and nothing else.

Indexes on table:

```
Indexes:
    "pa_key" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "pa_uniq" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (wbill)
    "pa_center_code_created_on_status_idx_new" btree (center_code, created_on, status)
```

The query is:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYSE 
SELECT "pa"."wbill" 
FROM "pa" 
WHERE ("pa"."center_code" = 'IND110030AAC' 
AND "pa"."status" IN ('Scheduled') 
AND "pa"."created_on" >= '2018-10-10T00:00:00+05:30'::timestamptz);
```

Query Plan:

```
   Index Scan using pa_center_code_created_on_status_idx_new on pa  (cost=0.69..3769.18 rows=38 width=13) (actual time=5.592..15.526 rows=78 loops=1)
   Index Cond: (((center_code)::text = 'IND110030AAC'::text) AND (created_on >= '2018-10-09 18:30:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND ((status)::text = 'Scheduled'::text))
     Planning time: 1.156 ms
     Execution time: 519.367 ms
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you share execution plan? Verbose..

Comment: Well the obvious problem is that you're doing `SELECT *`, and if that would include columns _other_ than what the index covers (namely `c_code`, `created_on`, and `status`), then the database engine would be forced to do another lookup, and as a result Postgres probably would not use the index at all.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, even if I am using select bill from , it is taking the same time

Comment: @dwir182, shared the query execution plan

Comment: Um...that's because `bill` is not covered in the index.  You are missing some basics about how an index works in SQL.

Comment: bill is not part of this index , but there is an another index also which is only on 'bill'

Comment: try `select c_code, created_on, status` instead of ( `select *` or `select bill` )

Comment: `status` should be the second column - or at least _before_  `created_on`. The rule of thumb is: first the columns you use for equality, then those you use for ranges.

Comment: Yes, but Postgres can typically only use one index at a time, so that other index won't help.

Comment: @Used_By_Already, I used 'select bill from' and results are same. I need the value of 'bill' actually which is another column in this table.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: Postgres will happily use more than one index if that promises to be faster. But it usually only uses additional indexes to reduce the number of rows, not to prevent accessing the table for those rows that are identified by the `where` clause

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, what if I have to check for multiple values for status column like status in ('Scheduled', 'Completed'). Should I still put it first

Comment: sigh, my suggestion was to ascertain any speed difference. I guess you can't waste ~500ms

Comment: @BhawandeepSingla columns that will be frequently searched against is best suit for index..

Comment: suggestions: A: include the full DDL of your table (with all indexes) B: include the full query don't abbreviate it or alter it, whatever it is you actually want to use. C: make sure the query plan is of that query. D: tell us the version of postgres in use. if some of those already exist great.

Comment: @Used_By_Already, I changed the 'waybill' to  'center_code' and getting the almost same results.

Comment: Postgres version:  PostgreSQL 9.5.10 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9), 64-bit

Comment: @BhawandeepSingla: an `IN` condition still qualifies as "equality". Do try an index on `(center_code, status, created_on)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, what about the cardinality ? Don't we need to consider it before deciding the order of indexes ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The index scan condition reads

```
(((center_code)::text = 'IND110030AAC'::text) AND
  (created_on >= '2018-10-09 18:30:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND
 ((status)::text = 'Scheduled'::text))
```

but the index scan itself is only over `(center_code, created_on)`, while the condition on `status` is applied as a filter.

Unfortunately this is not visible from the execution plan, but it follows from the following rule:

**An index scan will only use conditions if the rows satisfying the conditions are next to each other in the index.**

Let's consider this example (in index order):

```
 center_code  | created_on          | status
--------------+---------------------+-----------
 IND110030AAC | 2018-10-09 00:00:00 | Scheduled
 IND110030AAC | 2018-10-09 00:00:00 | Xtra
 IND110030AAC | 2018-10-10 00:00:00 | New
 IND110030AAC | 2018-10-10 00:00:00 | Scheduled
 IND110030AAC | 2018-10-11 00:00:00 | New
 IND110030AAC | 2018-10-11 00:00:00 | Scheduled
```

You will see that the query needs the 4th and 6th row.

PostgreSQL cannot scan the index with all three conditions, because the required rows are not next to each other. It will have to scan only with the first two conditions, because all rows satisfying those are right next to each other.

Your rule for multi-column indexes is wrong. The columns at the left of the index have to be the ones where `=` is used as comparison operator in the conditions.

The perfect index would be one on `(center_code, status, created_on)`.

Comment: Do you know if the order of the select column would matter here? Assuming the index is `(center_code, status, created_on)`, will `select center_code, status` be faster than `select status, center_code`?

Comment: @DevendraLattu You should ask a new question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75467655/does-the-order-of-the-columns-from-an-index-matter-during-the-selection

Answer (score 0):

One of the tips that I have learned from working is that when you created compound idx, the column with condition (=) should be priority and other conditions like (>, <, >=, <=, IN) will follow after.

Comment: This would qualify as a comment rather than an answer.