# Does the order of the columns from an index matter during the selection?

Tags: postgresql, select, indexing

I am curious to know if the order in which we select the columns affects the performance of an index.
Let's say I have an index on a postgres table
`constraint domain_index unique(username, firstname, country)`

Will the performance of the select queries be any different?

1. `Select username, firstname, country from table`
2. `Select country, firstname, username from table`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the order of the columns doesn't matter for the performance of an index-only scan without `WHERE` condition or `ORDER BY` clause. What really matters is how often the table gets vacuumed (more often is better).

You can reduce the size of the index (and thereby improve performance) if you index only the smallest of the columns and put the others into an `INCLUDE` clause:

```
CREATE INDEX ON tab (username) INCLUDE (country, firstname);
```

Comment: Can you please provide some examples?

Comment: No, because there is nothing to demonstrate. The performance of the two queries will be the same.